# Azure Functions loading performance

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm running some Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger. I noticed, very often that some functions take more than 10 secs to load and start my code.

[image]

As you can see, I put Trace at the begining and the end of the function. My code takes 2.79sec to run, but the function takes 8sec to load.

My functions use:

- c# and precompiled dll
- App Service running on B3
- Always On is activated
- The runtime is ~1

Update:
Sometimes, it takes 30sec with 100% CPU, just to load the function.
Remember, I use App Service Plan, not Consumption Plan.

Comment: Does this only happen when testing single operations? What happens after the first operation - does the speed change? Note: there is a discussion around this on the [github issues](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/131) page. You may want to join the discussion there. Currently, as written, this will likely be closed as off-topic - you shared no code, and it might be about service warm-up time or something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Function execution speed is extremely slow and inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878247/azure-function-execution-speed-is-extremely-slow-and-inconsistent)

Comment: not really, Im' using c# and precompiled dll, no js at all :)